# Python, unknown skip when reading/write document

Tags: python, xml

So i'm using python to help change a text file into xml. Somme of the text document below.

```
:
Breakfast Breads

Gluten Free Nut Loaf
Makes 1 loaf

150 g (51/2 oz./11/2 cups) 
almond meal
30 g (1 oz./1/4 cup)
walnuts, coarsely chopped
1/4 teaspoon 
gluten-free baking powder
```

I'm not sure if this can be replicated since it could be a ghost in the file itself. But if you could try that would be great.

To explain the current steps, my code is rudimentary, looking for the colon, it knows the next line is a general category, then switches a step variable. Then next step will skip empty lines '\r\n' until it  finds a not empty line which identified the start of a individual recipe, with its name. Next line in the loop, if empty change step, else write xml for serving size then change step.

Here we reach ingredients step. So the odd lines are qty, and even lines are the actual ingredient.

```
if step == 2:
    if line == empty: 
        continue
    else:
        xmlMenu.write("\n\t<ingredients>") 
        qty = line
        qtyXML = ("\n\t\t<qty>\n\t\t\t" + qty + "\t\t</qty>")
        xmlMenu.write(qtyXML)
        step = 2.2
        continue

if step == 2.2:
        if menu.next() == empty:
            ingredient = line
            pass
            ingredientXML = ("\n\t\t<ingredient>\n\t\t\t" + ingredient + "\t\t</ingredient>\n\t</ingredients>")
            xmlMenu.write(ingredientXML)
            step = 3
            continue

        else:
            ingredient = line
            ingredientXML = ("\n\t\t<ingredient>\n\t\t\t" + ingredient + "\t\t</ingredient>\n\t</ingredients>")
            xmlMenu.write(ingredientXML)
            step = 2
            continue
```

My problem, when it reaches the second set of qty/ingredient, it seemingly skips the qty for the almond meal and so screws up the whole xml file.

```
<recipe>
    <category>
        Breakfast Breads
    </category>
    <name>
        Gluten Free Nut Loaf
    </name>
    <servings>
        Makes 1 loaf
    </servings>
    <ingredients>
        <qty>
            150 g (51/2 oz./11/2 cups) 
        </qty>
        <ingredient>
            almond meal
        </ingredient>
    </ingredients>
    <ingredients>
        <qty>
            walnuts, coarsely chopped
        </qty>
        <ingredient>
            1/4 teaspoon 
        </ingredient>
    </ingredients>
```

Anyone have any thoughts if my code is just crap somewhere? Also, any suggestions for a better method to do this. I'm still beginner level programming.

//Edit for more code. The code still in the works at the end of the set when it starts a new recipe.

```
empty = '\r\n'
colon = ':'
new_contents = []

category = ''
categoryXML = ''

recipe = ''
recipeXML = ''

servings = ''
servingsXML = ''

ingrediants = ''
ingrediantsXML = ''

ingredient = ''
ingredientXML = ''
qty = ''
qtyXML = ''

instructions = ''
instructionsXML = ''

intNo = ''
intNoXML = ''
instruction = ''
instructionXML = ''

step = ''

x = 0

menu = open("menuTextFormat.txt", 'r')
xmlMenu = open('menuTextXML.txt', 'w')

for line in menu:
    # if not line.strip():
    #    continue
    #else:
    #     new_contents.append(line)
    if colon in line:
        step = 0
        continue

    if step == 0: 
        if not line:
            continue 
        else:       
            category = line
            categoryXML = "<recipe>\n\t<category>\n\t\t" + category + "\t</category>"
            xmlMenu.write(categoryXML)    
            step = 1            
            continue

    if step == 1:
        if line == empty:
            continue 
        else:
            recipe = line
            recipeXML = ("\n\t<name>\n\t\t" + recipe + "\t</name>")
            xmlMenu.write(recipeXML)
            step = 12
            continue

    if step == 12:
        if line == empty:
            step = 2
            continue
        else: 
            servings = line
            servingsXML = ("\n\t<servings>\n\t\t" + servings + "\t</servings>")
            xmlMenu.write(servingsXML)
            step = 2

            continue

    if step == 2:
        if line == empty: 
            continue
        else:
            xmlMenu.write("\n\t<ingredients>") 
            qty = line
            qtyXML = ("\n\t\t<qty>\n\t\t\t" + qty + "\t\t</qty>")
            xmlMenu.write(qtyXML)
            step = 22
            continue

    if step == 22:
            if menu.next() == empty:
                ingredient = line
                ingredientXML = ("\n\t\t<ingredient>\n\t\t\t" + ingredient + "\t\t</ingredient>\n\t</ingredients>")
                xmlMenu.write(ingredientXML)
                step = 3
                continue

            else:
                ingredient = line
                ingredientXML = ("\n\t\t<ingredient>\n\t\t\t" + ingredient + "\t\t</ingredient>\n\t</ingredients>")
                xmlMenu.write(ingredientXML)
                step = 2
                continue

    if step == 3:
        if line == empty:
            continue 
        else:
            x += 1
            intNoXML = ("\n\t\t<id>\n\t\t\t" + str(x) + "\n\t\t</id>")
            xmlMenu.write(intNoXML)
            instruction = line
            instructionXML = ("\n\t\t<instruction>\n\t\t\t" + instruction + "\t\t</instruction>")
            xmlMenu.write(instructionXML)
            if menu.next() == empty:
                step = 4
                continue
            else:
                continue
            continue

    if step == 4:
        if not menu.next():
            break
        else:
            step = 1
            continue


    #print line

#xmlMenu.write("".join(new_contents))


xmlMenu.close()
menu.close()


:
Breakfast Breads

Gluten Free Nut Loaf
Makes 1 loaf

150 g (51/2 oz./11/2 cups) 
almond meal
30 g (1 oz./1/4 cup)
walnuts, coarsely chopped
1/4 teaspoon 
gluten-free baking powder
1 teaspoon 
ground cinnamon
95 g (31/4 oz./3/4 cup) 
arrowroot (tapioca) flour
1/2 teaspoon 
sea salt
3 
organic eggs
1/2 teaspoon 
stevia powder
3 tablespoons 
grape seed oil
2 tablespoons 
coconut Milk
1 teaspoon 
apple cider vinegar

Preheat the oven to 180∫C (350∫F/Gas 4). 
Grease a 20 x 9 cm (8 x 31/2 inch) loaf (bar) tin.
Put the almond meal, walnuts, baking powder, cinnamon, arrowroot flour and salt in a large bowl and mix well with a wooden spoon. 
Crack the eggs into a separate bowl and whisk using an electric mixer until pale and fluffy, about 11/2 minutes. 
Add the stevia, grape seed oil, coconut milk and vinegar and mix gently. 
Pour the mixture into the dry ingredients and stir to combine. 
Spoon the mixture into the greased tin and bake for about 40 minutes, or until a skewer inserted in the centre of the loaf comes out clean. 
Remove the bread from the oven and leave to cool in the tin for a few minutes, before turning out onto a wire rack to cool completely. 
Enjoy the bread melt-in-the-mouth warm, or at room temperature with your favourite topping.  

Basic Gluten Free Loaf

2Ω cups 
blanched almond flour
Ω teaspoon 
baking soda
1 tsp. 
bicarbonate of soda
3 
eggs beaten
1 tsp. 
stevia powder
Ω teaspoon 
apple cider vinegar
!!
Pinch sea salt

Preheat oven to 250 degrees Celsius
Grease a small loaf pan
Combine dry ingredients in a bowl
In a separate bowl place eggs and apple cider vinegar
Spoon the mixture into loaf pan
Bake for 50 mins until set
Cool on wire rack
Slice when cool
```

more of the data.

Comment: can you post more of your code, including the part where you open the file. There are several things I would do differently when writing this piece of code. Not using floating points is one of them. but yea post your code and I'll write it how I would do it, and see if there are errors still.

Comment: Oh also can you specify if each text file is just one recipe. Or if there are multiple recipes per file (if there are multiple, please show how, at least two, would look in a file.

Comment: yup so pasted the full code now, and 2 of the recipes. I went through it by hand so each time sets of empty lines occur, its the signal for a new part of the recipe. The colon is the central part to say a new category is occuring, but also implies new recipes next. All the recipes are in the one file.

Comment: Perfect, give me 10 minutes. This should be no problem at all.

Comment: No problem, i'm still looking at it myself. Do you know if when i'm looking at a line, and i call .next() that in the next iteration its skipped it? or it's still on the original line?

Comment: Well I'm almost done, I'm on the procedure part...

Comment: P.S. That was your original problem. .next() does indeed call the next line >.< This problem is solved in the code I submitted, because I'm working line for line anyway. This is actually why I manually list the first item in ingredients and procedure. After listing the first item, I jump into a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You'll notice a couple things...**
1. I removed a lot of the variables you listed prior to the loop. You don't really need to list them before the loop.
2. I switched it to a while loop. I personally like the appeal of being able to read things one line at a time
3. I wrote the category in the name section, this is just cause the category isn't always listed when a new recipe starts, so I figured it'd be best to use the last known category and insert that in front of every new recipe.
4. Your serving size wasn't always listed, so I took the liberty of adding an check in there so it would return "serving size not listed" just in case.
5. I used a loop on the ingredients.

**Notes:**
1. All blank lines are completely ignored because of the `and line` in every `if step == 1 and line:`. The variable `line` is stripped of all line returns, so the while loop skips all new lines. The steps just make sure we're doing the right thing after each blank line is skipped.
2. The Nut Loaf sounds delicious

**Code:**

```
category=''
step=0

menu = open("menuTextFormat.txt", 'r')
xml = open('menuTextXML.txt', 'w')

xml.write("<recipe>\n")

while 1:
    line = menu.readline()
    if not line:
        break

    #after checking for EOF, remove \n
    line = line.rstrip()

    #category
    if ":" in line:
        #set category as next line
        category = menu.readline().rstrip()
        step=1
        continue

    #name & servings
    if step == 1 and line:
        #write category
        xml.write("\t<category>\n\t\t" + category + "\n\t</category>\n")
        #write name
        xml.write("\t<name>\n\t\t" + line + "\n\t</name>\n")

        #check for serving size
        servings = menu.readline().rstrip()
        if not servings:
            xml.write("\t<servings>\n\t\tno serving size listed\n\t</servings>\n")
        else:
            xml.write("\t<servings>\n\t\t" + servings + "\n\t</servings>\n")

        step=2
        continue

    #ingredients
    if step == 2 and line:
        #write first ingredient, then loop for rest
        xml.write("\t<qty>\n\t\t" + line + "\n\t</qty>\n")
        xml.write("\t<ingredient>\n\t\t" + menu.readline().rstrip() + "\n\t</ingredient>\n")

        #loop for incredients
        while 1:
            qty = menu.readline().rstrip()
            #no more incredients, break loop
            if not qty:
                break

            xml.write("\t<qty>\n\t\t" + qty + "\n\t</qty>\n")
            xml.write("\t<ingredient>\n\t\t" + menu.readline().rstrip() + "\n\t</ingredient>\n")

        step=3
        continue

    #procedure
    if step == 3 and line:
        #write first step, then loop for rest
        xml.write("\t<procedure>\n")
        xml.write("\t\t<step>\n\t\t\t" + line + "\n\t\t</step>\n")

        #loop for steps
        while 1:
            step = menu.readline().rstrip()
            #no more steps, break loop
            if not step:
                break

            xml.write("\t\t<step>\n\t\t\t" + step + "\n\t\t</step>\n")

        xml.write("\t</procedure>\n")

        step=1
        continue

xml.write("</recipe>")
menu.close()
xml.close()
```

**Output:**

```
<recipe>
    <category>
        Breakfast Breads
    </category>
    <name>
        Gluten Free Nut Loaf
    </name>
    <servings>
        Makes 1 loaf
    </servings>
    <qty>
        150 g (51/2 oz./11/2 cups)
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        almond meal
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        30 g (1 oz./1/4 cup)
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        walnuts, coarsely chopped
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        1/4 teaspoon
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        gluten-free baking powder
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        1 teaspoon
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        ground cinnamon
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        95 g (31/4 oz./3/4 cup)
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        arrowroot (tapioca) flour
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        1/2 teaspoon
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        sea salt
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        3
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        organic eggs
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        1/2 teaspoon
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        stevia powder
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        3 tablespoons
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        grape seed oil
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        2 tablespoons
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        coconut Milk
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        1 teaspoon
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        apple cider vinegar
    </ingredient>
    <procedure>
        <step>
            Preheat the oven to 180∫C (350∫F/Gas 4).
        </step>
        <step>
            Grease a 20 x 9 cm (8 x 31/2 inch) loaf (bar) tin.
        </step>
        <step>
            Put the almond meal, walnuts, baking powder, cinnamon, arrowroot flour and salt in a large bowl and mix well with a wooden spoon.
        </step>
        <step>
            Crack the eggs into a separate bowl and whisk using an electric mixer until pale and fluffy, about 11/2 minutes.
        </step>
        <step>
            Add the stevia, grape seed oil, coconut milk and vinegar and mix gently.
        </step>
        <step>
            Pour the mixture into the dry ingredients and stir to combine.
        </step>
        <step>
            Spoon the mixture into the greased tin and bake for about 40 minutes, or until a skewer inserted in the centre of the loaf comes out clean.
        </step>
        <step>
            Remove the bread from the oven and leave to cool in the tin for a few minutes, before turning out onto a wire rack to cool completely.
        </step>
        <step>
            Enjoy the bread melt-in-the-mouth warm, or at room temperature with your favourite topping.
        </step>
    </procedure>
    <category>
        Breakfast Breads
    </category>
    <name>
        Basic Gluten Free Loaf
    </name>
    <servings>
        no serving size listed
    </servings>
    <qty>
        2Ω cups
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        blanched almond flour
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        Ω teaspoon
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        baking soda
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        1 tsp.
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        bicarbonate of soda
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        3
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        eggs beaten
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        1 tsp.
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        stevia powder
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        Ω teaspoon
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        apple cider vinegar
    </ingredient>
    <qty>
        !!
    </qty>
    <ingredient>
        Pinch sea salt
    </ingredient>
    <procedure>
        <step>
            Preheat oven to 250 degrees Celsius
        </step>
        <step>
            Grease a small loaf pan
        </step>
        <step>
            Combine dry ingredients in a bowl
        </step>
        <step>
            In a separate bowl place eggs and apple cider vinegar
        </step>
        <step>
            Spoon the mixture into loaf pan
        </step>
        <step>
            Bake for 50 mins until set
        </step>
        <step>
            Cool on wire rack
        </step>
        <step>
            Slice when cool
        </step>
    </procedure>
</recipe>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. A lot of what you've written is pretty much what I wanted to do but was stuck with primitive understanding. I do have a question, 'while 1' how does that work?

Comment: same thing as `while True` or `while 1==1`, it just loops forever with no condition. I posted a P.S. in the original comments, the .next() was messing up your code. I dunno, I felt like writing it from scratch. I'm not sure if you really care but this way seems prettier to me :/ Also I forgot to paste the `menu.close()` and `xml.close()`. I'm gonna edit my post right now to include those.

Comment: A for loop reads line for line, but a while loop you have to manually call when you're reading a line. I feel like it's more flexible this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be easier to understand if you divide it up into functions where each function is responsible for recognizing just a small feature, e.g.:

```
def parse_next_receipe(lines, pos=0):
    while 1:
        if pos >= len(lines):
            break

        line = lines[pos]
        if line.strip() == ':':
            pos, receipe = parse_receipe(lines, pos)
            yield receipe  # or write it directly to the xml file...
        else:
            pos += 1

def parse_receipe(lines, pos):
    pos, name = parse_name(lines, pos)
    pos, description = parse_description(lines, pos)
    ingredients = []

    while 1:
        pos, ingredient = parse_ingredient(lines, pos)
        if pos == -1:
            break
        else:
            ingredients.append(ingredient)

    return (name, description, ingredients)


def parse_name(lines, pos): ...

def parse_description(lines, pos): ...

def parse_ingredient(lines, pos):
    try:
        pos, quantity = parse_quantity(lines, pos)
        pos, ingredient = parse_ingredientname(lines, pos)
    except ValueError:
        return -1, None

def parse_quantity(lines, pos):
    line = lines[pos]
    if line[0] in '0123456789':
        # line starts with a number
        return pos + 1, line
    raise ValueError("Line %r doesn't contain a quantity" % line)

def parse_ingredientname(lines, pos):
    line = lines[pos]
    if line:
        # any non-empty line is ok as an ingredient name
        return pos + 1, line
    raise ValueError("Expected an ingredient name, found blank line, lineno=%d" % pos)
```

this is called recursive descent parsing.

In the example, each function takes a `pos` which is the line number where it's supposed to start looking, and returns the "next" line to look at + the value that it found.

I've used two different methods to indicate a parsing error: returning `-1` as a position (and `None` as the value), or raising an exception.  Either one can be useful.